# Get error year by using NSDateFormatter transform NSDate to NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter * formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateFormat = NSLocalizedString(@"yyyy-MM-dd", nil);
return [formatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Today is "2017-06-09", but the result is "0029-06-09" on the user's iphone. How can I fix it?

Comment: I have found this problem is caused by Japanese calendar

Comment: Is it possible to get?

Comment: 2017-06-09 @gongtaoatbupt did you want this result ?

Answer (score 0):

What is the "yyyy-MM-dd" localized string for ?
Or you can just set:

`formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd";`

Comment: In my code, it's the same. The localizeds string is "yyyy-MM-dd".

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your local to NSDateFormatter

```
    [formatter setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:"jp"];
```